# How to check if an access token from a request comes from the correct user in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

After a user logins successfully, he/she gets an access token for later requests. My problem is that as long as I have the valid token of a user, I can make a request on behalf of that user.  I would like to ask how to check if the access token in a request comes from its correct user?

I am using Laravel Passport for the authentication.

Comment: are you using JWT tokens?

Answer (score 0):

The token is the way to claim requests come from a certain user.

If the token gets compromised, there only way to understand if requests are legit is to check ip addresses / user-agent but basically you have to consider that the token itself represents the user.